# Search fails to find matching issues

Tags: bug, search

When I search for the string `"cwlogs.push.reader" "reason: timestamp could not be parsed from message"` on Google, one of the top results is the following Stack Overflow question: [AWS Clouwatch logs agent (awslogs) going crazy and writing GBs to log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154448/aws-clouwatch-logs-agent-awslogs-going-crazy-and-writing-gbs-to-log-file)

However, when I then attempt to search for the same terms in Stack Overflow, I get [no results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22cwlogs.push.reader%22%20%22reason%3A%20timestamp%20could%20not%20be%20parsed%20from%20message%22). Even when I simply search for `"timestamp could not be parsed from message"`, I still get [0 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22timestamp%20could%20not%20be%20parsed%20from%20message%22). I would expect to see  [AWS Clouwatch logs agent (awslogs) going crazy and writing GBs to log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154448/aws-clouwatch-logs-agent-awslogs-going-crazy-and-writing-gbs-to-log-file) in the results at the *very least*, but even it doesn't show up. I wonder if there are other matching questions that are not being returned?

Comment: [Cross posted on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342723/search-fails-to-find-matching-issues).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like

```
code is not indexed at all
```

but normal text is. Try for example searching for "rythm of 10 per millisecond", which will yield the post in question. Google indexes the whole post of course and does not distinguish between code formatting and normal text.

I personally would prefer that the code parts are indexed, either (feature-request!)

**Edit:**

I just learned, that you can search through the `code` parts by prefixing the search term with **code:**, as for example in

```
code:"timestamp could not be parsed from message"
```

This of course requires that you guess that the search term is indeed formatted as code.

Comment: Even prefixing text that appears in code with `code:` doesn't work.  See 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794923.  Try searching for `excel vba displaystatusbar clipboard`.  Stackoverflow can't find this.  The word `displaystatusbar` appears in code.  Now try searching for `excel vba code:displaystatusbar clipboard`.  Stackoverflow _still_ can't find this.